# Find the new one with Python

Tags: python

I have a list of objects called for sample "A1_YYYYMMdd, B1_YYYYMMdd, A3B3_YYYYMMdd, etc..."

For me the characters before the "*" identify the name of the block and the numbers after the "*" identify the date.

I want create a new "object" containing only the new one for each block.
es.

a= 'A1B1_20160213','A1B1_20161001','B2_20160202','B2_20161010
run script
b='A1B1_20161001','B2_20161010'

I try to write this but doesn't work.

```
##########################  TEST 1
import string
delivery=['A1B1_20160213','A1B1_20161001','B2_20160202','B2_20161010','F3_20160203']
dely=string.split(str(delivery),"_")
l=len(dely)
##print l
list(dely)
print type(dely)
d=[]
print type(d)
for i in range(0,l,2):
    print i
    if i==0:
        d=dely[i]
        list(d)
        print type(d)
    else:
        print type(d)
        list(d)
        print type(d)
        d.append(dely[i])
        print d
print d

##########################  TEST 2
import string
delivery=['A1_20160213','A1_20161001','B2_20160202','B2_20161010','B2_201610113','A2B2_20160202','A2B2_20161010',\
'F3_20160203','F3_20160204','F3_20160205','F3_20160206']

delivery.sort
l=len(delivery)
for i in range(0,l-1,1):
    print i
    a=delivery[i]
    b=delivery[i+1]
    aa=a[:2]
    bb=b[:2]
    if aa==bb:
        if a<b:
            c=b
            print c
        elif a>b:
            c=a
            print c
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you keep this `<name_date>` format/order and date formatting (e.g., YYYYMMDD), the code below should do what you are after.

It first populates a python dictionary with the names as keys and then finds the *largest* date among all possible formatted date strings. It then repacks the list as in the original format

```
delivery=['A1B1_20160213','A1B1_20161001','B2_20160202','B2_20161010','F3_20160203']
result={}
for d in delivery:
    part,date=d.split("_")
    result.setdefault(part,[]).append(date)

b=["_".join([k,sorted(result[k],reverse=True)[0]]) for k in result.keys()]
```

Comment: +1 for using .setdefault. I haven't seen that before, but will be using it from now on, instead of the more long-winded if x not in y.keys()... etc.

Comment: @jon_two, this was the case for me, checking `dict.has_key` before pushing items in and you will see setdefault is immensely convenient (somewhat crazy). Here you see a list example but it also gets set or dictionary and can use add and setdefault methods, respectively. For me, everything has started with [this overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key/12906014#comment58277022_12906014).